# SharedPreference or Sqlite Caching and Network Caching Confusion

Tags: android, sqlite, caching, sharedpreferences, robospice

After going the storage options in android and libraries like **robospice** and **picasso**, i am a bit stuck here or say confused.

- For persistent data, i can go with **sharedPreference** for primitive data types or **Sqlite** for relational data, and this will be removed by android OS when app is uninstalled.
- For caching **Picasso** use HttpClient cache.
- For Networking or say for Rest call, library like **RoboSpice** uses Cache.

I have recently implemented and used all of them in my android application, and i also understand the concept of sharedPreference and Sqlite.

But, when it comes to **RoboSpice**, i am a bit confused as it caches the data but again when an app is killed and again started, it again hits the server for the same data rather than using it from the cache.

Same case with **Picasso**.

How exactly caching of Robospice and Picasso is different than sharedPreference and Sqlite?

Where their cached data is stored? If not in some file, say in device main memory then they arent used again when app restarts.

Picasso uses http client cache, and caches only static data, like images, that's is also fine.But, in case of network library like robospice, what type of caching they use. Is it stored in some file like sharedPref does? Will it be available after application restarts? Also in case of picasso, will the http cache, will be available after app restarts?

Any help or guideline on this topic will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared Preferences and Sqlite happen to be very different from HTTP caching. You use the first two to persist data between app sessions.

If you wish you can fetch data over the network and save it either to shared preferences or to sqlite and then you would be creating your own caching system on top of those layers. However you would be disregarding the wishes of the web app or the HTTP server when you do that.

HTTP client libraries on the other hand are bound to check with the web server if the content has expired, and the chances are very likely that if it's dynamically generated content, the web server will tell it that the content has indeed expired. So they have no choice but to fetch the data again.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Shared Preferences and Sqlite is used to persist data and will be removed when app is uninstalled, that's fine though. Picasso uses http client cache, and caches only static data, like images, that's is also fine.But, in case of network library like robospice, what type of caching they use. Is it stored in some file like sharedPref does? Will it be available after application restarts? Also in case of picasso, will the http cache, will be available after app restarts?

Comment: All those client libraries save their state to the apps data folder so will be available after restart but they too will be removed if the app is uninstalled. Additionally there is no guarantee that the library will be able to reuse cached content. It happens all the time with desktop chrome and firefox too

Comment: So, in the scenarios where the app data is to resued after the application  is killed and started again. It's better to go for sharedPref or sqlite?Network libs are better for caching b/w activities and screen rotation.Please correct me, if i am wrong.

Comment: NO it's not a case of what's better here. It's a case of what works for you. HTTP libraries cache HTTP responses according to the rules of the HTTP protocol. You can use sqlite or sharedpreference to cache objects according to your own rules. You have to decide what's suitable for you.

Comment: Than you for the clarifications mate.